# calling a field of a models in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a model class for eg.

```
class A(models.Model):
    first = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def any_func(self):
        string = 'first'
        return self.string
```

Now if I call this function it shows me an error that

> A does not have any field string

How to clear or correct this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `getattr`:

> `getattr(...)`
>
> ```
> `getattr(object, name[, default]) -> value`
>
> Get a named attribute from an object; `getattr(x, 'y')` is equivalent to `x.y`.
> When a default argument is given, it is returned when the attribute doesn't
> exist; without it, an exception is raised in that case.
> ```

Here is an example:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __init__(self, foo):
...         self.bar = foo
...     def get_stuff(self, stuff):
...         return getattr(self, stuff, 'Not Found')
...
>>> i = A('hello')
>>> i.get_stuff('zoo')
'Not Found'
>>> i.get_stuff('bar')
'hello'
```

`getattr` will take a string, and if it is an attribute of the object, it will return that attribute (as if you did `i.something`). The third argument is the default it should return if nothing was found.